# 'unexpected end of file' with pushing items to an array with jimp

Tags: node.js

i'm trying to overlay multiple images onto one single image. it works to an extent, but it isn't working how i want it to.

```
global.images = [];

fs.readdirSync('./images').forEach(function(file) {
    images.push(file);

    if (debug) {
        console.log(chalk.green('[Debug] Pushed ' + chalk.blue(file) + ' to the array.'));
    }
});
executeEdit(images);

function executeEdit(list) {
    var jimps = [];
    var x = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        x = x + 150;

        setTimeout((function(i) {
            return function() {
                jimps.push(jimp.read('images/' + images[i]));
            }
        })(i), 10 * x);
    }
```

this code throws an error of:
 `(node:15352) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: unexpected end of file
    at Inflate.zlibOnError (zlib.js:153:15)
    at Inflate._processChunk (D:\ImageTest\node_modules\pngjs\lib\sync-inflate.js:110:28)
    at zlibBufferSync (D:\ImageTest\node_modules\pngjs\lib\sync-inflate.js:151:17)
    at inflateSync (D:\ImageTest\node_modules\pngjs\lib\sync-inflate.js:155:10)
    at module.exports (D:\ImageTest\node_modules\pngjs\lib\parser-sync.js:79:20)
    at Object.exports.read [as image/png] (D:\ImageTest\node_modules\pngjs\lib\png-sync.js:10:10)
    at Jimp.parseBitmap (D:\ImageTest\node_modules\@jimp\core\dist\utils\image-bitmap.js:117:53)
    at Jimp.parseBitmap (D:\ImageTest\node_modules\@jimp\core\dist\index.js:498:32)
    at D:\ImageTest\node_modules\@jimp\core\dist\index.js:440:15
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:511:3)
(node:15352) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)`

and i have no idea why. it may be due to reading from the directory and adding it to an array as just doing `var images = ['file.png', 'file2.png' ]` works fine.

if anyone has any ideas on how to fix, please let me know.

thanks!

**edit**:
doing this works, but it only chooses the last image and not any others :/

```
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        x = x + 150;
        // console.log(i);

        var image = {
            _integer: i,
            _image: images[i],
            func: function() {
                jimps.push(jimp.read('images/' + this._image));
                // console.log(this._integer);
            }
        }

        setTimeout(function() {image.func()}, x);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hint is the message `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`: you are missing the fact that `jimp` is actually asynchronous (either callbacks or promises).  In your case, since there is no callback passed to `jimp.read()` it assumes promises are used but you are not using them correctly.

If you replace `// console.log(this._integer);` by `console.log(jimps)`, you will see something like this:

```
[ Promise { <pending> } ]
[ Promise { <Jimp 32x32> }, Promise { <pending> } ]
....
```

I am not sure what you are doing with the `jimps` array at all (nor why you are using a `setTimeout()` here), but you can perhaps do something like this (if have simplified a bit by removing some logs and removing the `setTimeout()` stuff).  This is now proper promise code.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var jimp = require('jimp');

const images = [];
fs.readdirSync('./images').forEach(function(file) {
    images.push(file);
    console.log('[Debug] Pushed', file, ' to the array');
});

executeEdit(images);
console.log('waiting for executeEdit() to terminate');

function executeEdit(list) {
  let jimp_read_promises = []

  for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
      jimp_read_promises.push( jimp.read('images/' + images[i]))
  }

  Promise.all(jimp_read_promises).then( loadedimgs => {
    loadedimgs.map( img => {
      console.log( img )
    })
  })
}
```

So this would print the following

```
[Debug] Pushed 7035a55d06033e435be112c0969b1820.png  to the array
[Debug] Pushed aa5ef861d490a11fe20806e83c6dc64b.png  to the array
[Debug] Pushed crayon.png  to the array
waiting for executeEdit() to terminate
<Jimp 32x32>
<Jimp 48x48>
<Jimp 256x256>
```

So the 3 files (in my case) are read synchronously then executeEdit() is called. We build an array of promise objects then call Promise.all() which will wait till all promises are resolved.  The value `loadedimgs` is an array with the result of each promise (in the same order as the promises).  You can then loop over that array as you see fit (here I used a `map` call but a for loop will do.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the response! however, i am encountering problems when running this code. i still get the same error `unexpected end of file` and also the error `await jimp.read('images/' + images[i])
            ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`. here is my current code: https://pastebin.com/raw/CsgPii9B - if you would have any idea on how to fix this, it would really help :^)

Comment: could the unexpected end of file be due to one of your image being incorrect or corrupted ?  Also can you tell me which version of node you are using ? The code I pasted was in a file called `test.js` which I ran with `node test.js` without issue. My version of node is v10.8.0. I will look at the pastebin.

Comment: it might be to do with the version of node im using: im on `v8.11.2` ://

Comment: this is weird. I just installed v8.11.2 and run the file from pastebin unchanged. and I don't get any error message of any king neither releated to async nor to unexpected eof :( The output is here https://pastebin.com/raw/pJAkZ7zf (the undefined are normals as image[i] is not valid anymore by the time the promise is handled)  Can you try with a few different images (incl. background) just to be sure ?

Comment: ill quickly make a youtube video that showcases my issue gimme a min

Comment: in order to at least avoid the async issue, here is a version that uses callbacks https://pastebin.com/raw/kjBQz7rz At that point, we only have to deal with the EOF issue :)

Comment: alright - ill try that in a second thanks :) here is the video: https://youtu.be/fTMAFCrbfxs

Comment: the pastebin with callbacks weirdly throws a bunch of jimp errors such as w and h must be numbers and invalid settings specified for the resizer

Comment: the youtube video is a nice idea :) I truly thinks that the second image is corrupted or cannot be read by Jimp. Can you try to duplicate the working one a few times under other names and see if it works better.  I think the solution I gave you with either async or callback does work as expected, though.  Let me know.

Comment: This is weird. I am on mac OS and get absolutely no errors at all :(  And those errors doesn't look like they are due to your code really

Comment: this is super weird. duplicating the image worked perfectly, but when i add more than 5 images to the directory, the program never outputs finished / creates a new image. any ideas on that?

Comment: Well, yes. You still have an asynchronous issue in this code due to the for loop.  Give me a few minutes to try and make a proposition to you.

Comment: @JoeStevens I have updated my answer above with proper promises handling. We build the array of promises (each being a jimp.read() promise), use Promise.all() to wait for them all to finish and then process the array of results.  This looks good to me ... https://pastebin.com/raw/Jif6hgGQ for the copy/paste :)  Hope that's the final one :)

Comment: thank you very much! it now works perfectly. thanks for all of your help :)